# Integrating Mirth with Swagger (Having API documentation)

Tags: xml, api, xml-parsing, swagger, mirth

Is there a way to integrate Swagger with Mirth Connect channels?
Or Is there any alternative for auto documentation for Mirth Channels APIs - even through writing XMls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to https://yourserver.com:port/api

Comment: @Duefectu thanks , but this is for mirth generic APIs , not for our channels (custom made) APIs